# How to trigger EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION exception to test handlers?

Tags: windows, c++, exception

I have a task to try out some things featured in Microsoft SEH for illegal instruction exception. I knew, that is basically wrong command for CPU, but how I can trigger this by myself to catch it and handle?
P.S. Is there any article where I can read about this parcticullar exception?

Comment: might be a question for stack exchange?!

Comment: you can use [`__ud2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/ud2?view=vs-2017) for *x86/x64* in msvc

Comment: It's works. Thanks a lot. P.S. Is there any similar function for trying illegal instruction handling in Linux (gcc/g++ compiler)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RaiseException` function using the Win32 API. This function raises an exception in the current thread of the process from which is called on.